# Inconsistency in number of users in analytics console

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In the Firebase Analytics console for my app, number of users for screen_view event and first_open event are different. Users who have fired screen_view event are around 5% more than the users who have fired first_open . Shouldn't this number be same?
Or is there something I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score -1):

Yep, that's [expected](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485). Here's the `first_open` description:

> Triggered the first time a user launches an app after installing or
>   reinstalling it.
>
> This event is not triggered when a user downloads the app onto a
>   device, but instead when he or she first uses it. To see raw download
>   numbers, look in Google Play Developer Console or in iTunesConnect.

The `screen_view` event is triggered *every time* a user views a screen. So 5% means you're just getting started, good luck!

Comment: I'm not counting the number of times this event is fired, I'm concerned with the unique users who have fired these events. Shouldn't that be same?

Comment: Ohhh... are you looking at a time range? Old users who've had your app for a while won't be included in the last 30 days of `first_open` for example. You'd have to use all time metrics.

Comment: We're setting the time range from before including Firebase in the project to now.

Comment: Huh, then I'm not sure.